# JavaScript Closures and Parentheses

Tags: javascript, closures

1.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var incrementClickCounts = (function(){
    var clickCounts = 0;
    return function() {
      return ++clickCounts;
    }
  })()()

</script>
<input type="button" value="clickkkk" onclick="alert(incrementClickCounts);" />
```

2.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

  var incrementClickCounts = (function(){
  var clickCounts = 0;
  return function() {
    return ++clickCounts;
}
})()

</script>
<input type="button" value="clickkkk" onclick="alert(incrementClickCounts());" />
```

I'm working on closures, and I came across this example. The second example works correctly by incrementing the clickCounts every time it is clicked, but the first example only returns a value of '1'.

I am having some trouble distinguishing on how to use the parentheses to correctly invoke the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first case, `incrementClickCounts` contains a number; in the second case, a function. Let's break down the execution :

First case :

```
var incrementClickCounts = (function(){
    var clickCounts = 0;
    return function() {
      return ++clickCounts;
    }
  }) // declares a function
() // executes that function - returns another function that initializes clickCounts to 0 and increments it to 1
() // executes the returned function --> outputs 1 and stores it in the incrementClickCounts variable.

// So incrementClickCounts contains a NUMBER = 1
```

So :

```
alert(incrementClickCounts)
```

will alert "1".

Second case :

```
var incrementClickCounts = (function(){
  var clickCounts = 0;
  return function() {
    return ++clickCounts;
}
}) // declares a function
() // executes that function - 
   // returns another function that initializes clickCounts to 0 and increments it to 1
   // This function is stored in incrementClickCounts

// So incrementClickCounts contains a FUNCTION that you cal call to increment clickCounts
```

So :

```
alert(incrementClickCounts())
```

will execute that function and increment clickCounts.

Answer (score 0):

This expression builds a function:

```
(function(){
 var clickCounts = 0;
 return function() {
   return ++clickCounts;
 }
})()
```

Let's call it `incrementFunction`.

In the first case, you do

```
var incrementClickCounts = incrementFunction();
```

That is you call the function and you store the result.  Every time you click the button, you do `alert(incrementClickCounts);`. So you're just alerting the result of the initial call of `incrementFunction`.

In the second case, you do

```
var incrementClickCounts = incrementFunction;
```

That is you store **the function**. Every time you click the button, you do `alert(incrementClickCounts());`. So you call the function every time.